# Search inside array in jsonb column in Postgres using Knex

Tags: typescript, postgresql, knex.js

My table has data column which holds jsonb values with the structure below.

```
Table: item_details

id: uuid,
data: jsonb
```

---

```
Item = {
    itemNumber: 73463,
    itemName: pqr,
    description: [
      {
      id: abc,
      type: xyz,
      units: 6
      },
      {
      id: def,
      type: stu,
      units: 9
      }
    ]
 }
```

When I recieve a description object, I need to check if its present inside description Array. I am using Postgres database with typescript alongwith Knex. I tried many approaches but none of them worked.

Right now out of all the approcahes I have tried, the below runs without any errors but it returns undefined.

```
async findByDescription (description: Description) {
    const query = this.client<ItemRow>('item_details')
      .withSchema('item_schema')
      .select()
      .whereRaw('data->>? = ?', ['description' , description])
    const result = await query
    return result
  }
```

Sample data

```
    id                    data
x-y-z             {
                  itemNumber: 73463,
                  itemName: Train,
                  description: [
                    {
                    id: 263761,
                    type: Superfast,
                    units: 6
                    },
                    {
                    id: 345467,
                    type: Bullet,
                    units: 9
                    }
                  ]
                }

a-b-c           {
                  itemNumber: 83483,
                  itemName: pqr,
                  description: [
                    {
                      id: 263761,
                      type: Superfast,
                      units: 6
                      },
                      {
                      id: 445787,
                      type: Normal,
                      units: 18
                      }
                  ]
                }
```

I have got a description object

```
{
     id: 263761,
     type: Superfast,
     units: 6
   }
```

Now I need to search this object inside data->description array. If a match is found, the row containing that should be returned. In the above case, it will be both the records with the id x-y-z and a-b-c

Comment: Try printing the query to see what SQL it is generating. With JSONB unfortunately I inevitably have to resort to raw queries :(

Comment: There is no `data->>'item'` in your row. Only `data->>'itemNumber'` and `data->>'itemName'`

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I have edited the question. Updated item with the description.

Comment: I don't think you want to compare arrays of objects like that, as text. As Michael said, please show the generated sql queries. Add some sample data of your table, the `description` value you are passing, and describe what result you expect.

Comment: But really this whole endeavour is probably a good reminder why it's not a good idea to store data in unnormalised form in a relational database.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for your input. I have added sample data and the required output. I am still unsure about what the correct query should look like, so trying for that. Once I get that will edit and add the same.

Comment: Thanks. For a "array contains object looking like X" query, you'll probably want to use the [`@>` containment operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the required results with the below approach

```
async findByDescription (desc: Description) {
    const query = this.client<ItemRow>('item_details')
      .withSchema('item_schema')
      .select()
      .whereRaw(`data->'description' @> '${JSON.stringify([desc])}'`)
    console.log(query.toSQL().sql)
    const result = await query
    return result
  }
```

Comment: You should pass `JSON.stringify([desc])` as a query parameter, so that it is properly escaped, instead of interpolating it in the SQL